# XD to Flutter plugin not exporting widgets

Tags: flutter, adobe-xd

I made a **UI** with ***Adobe XD*** and after I finished it, I tried exporting all *widgets* but nothing is showing in **Android Studio**.

I added the `adobe_xd`: dependency.

I unlinked all components but it's still not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now the only way to ***export all widgets*** is to *uncheck* the **prototype** **interaction** option.

Comment: Doesn't **XD to Flutter** support **prototype interactions**?

Comment: it does but the interactions are limited

Answer (score 0):

My initial export created prototype interactions, but now going back and having added more interactions and more artboards, the plugin will not export while I have the Prototype Interactions box checked.